# Modify regex to add new feature

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm currently using the below regex to remove domain names and create short names for hosts in a list of servers.

```
(-net|-bck|-adm|\..*)(\..*|$) -> blank
```

Now, I want to modify this so that it can also convert any hostnames that contains UPPERCASE to lowercase. I'm currently using the below regex to perform that

```
(\w) -> \L$1
```

Any ideas how can I merge both regexes as one?

I'm looking for a regex which would make conversion like below:

```
Hostname  | New Hostname
--------- | ------------
test1-net | test1
Test2-adm | test2
TEST3     | test3
TEST-prod | test-prod
Test5-bkp | test5-bkp
test.nic  | test
Test6-bck | test6
=========================
```

Hope the above example helps in understanding my requirement.

Comment: What tool do you use to interpret your regex ? sed ? Could you show us the exact command you use along with a sample input/output ?

Comment: @Aserre I'm not certain of the tool/command that interprets the regex. I put the regex code in the GUI Command section of the Application and it interprets the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what tool are you using, but would not help just concatenating the regexps?

```
(.*)(-net|-bck|-adm|\..*)(\..*|$) -> \L$1
```

Everything in the first group will be lowercased, and the rest `(-net|-bck|-adm|\..*)(\..*|$)` will be removed.

Note that nothing may follow `(\..*|$)` as `.*` eats and discards everything until the string end.

**EDIT:** If you want to lowercase everything and not remove anything if the second regex does not match, just make the second regex optional with `?` as in the following:

```
(.*)((-net|-bck|-adm|\..*)(\..*|$))? -> \L$1
```

Comment: The concated regex seems to work only for those values where the second can be matched, otherwise it doesn't work. I think I need to modify my question to add in that info as well.

Comment: What do you want to do if the second regex does not match? Just lowercase everything and not remove anything?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm looking for. I've also editing my question to add few examples.

Comment: Then make the second regex optional with `?` as in:
`(.*)((-net|-bck|-adm|\..*)(\..*|$))? -> \L$1`

Comment: I added the alternative with the optional second regexp to the answer.